# Telephone field validation using JQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a contact form with simple jQuery validation, and sending the form content using Php. I'm trying to include a phone field validation. JavaScript works fine when validating the phone field and auto format/correcting/completing the phone field. However the Php script is not working. It works fine if I remove the the phoneNumber field.

```js
(function($) {

    "use strict";
    
     /* Alert Boxes
    * ------------------------------------------------------ */
    var clAlertBoxes = function() {

        $('.alert-box').on('click', '.alert-box__close', function() {
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(500);
        }); 

    };


   /* Contact Form
    * ------------------------------------------------------ */
    var clContactForm = function() {
        
        /* local validation */
        $('#contactForm').validate({
        
            /* submit via ajax */
            submitHandler: function(form) {
    
                var sLoader = $('.submit-loader');
    
                $.ajax({
    
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function() { 
    
                        sLoader.slideDown("slow");
    
                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
    
                        // Message was sent
                        if (msg == 'OK') {
                            sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                            $('.message-warning').fadeOut();
                            $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                            $('.message-success').fadeIn();
                        }
                        // There was an error
                        else {
                            sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                            $('.message-warning').html(msg);
                            $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");
                        }
    
                    },
                    error: function() {
    
                        sLoader.slideUp("slow"); 
                        $('.message-warning').html("Something went wrong! Please try again.");
                        $('.message-warning').slideDown("slow");
    
                    }
    
                });
            }
    
        });
    };
   })(jQuery);
```

```css
fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.message-warning, 
.message-success {
    display: none;
    background: #111111;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3.6rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.message-warning {
    color: #ff6163;
}

.message-success {
    color: #39b54a;
}

.message-warning i, .message-success i {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

/* form loader
 * ----------------------------------------------- */
 .submit-loader {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 1.8rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.submit-loader .text-loader {
    display: none;
    font-family: "montserrat-regular", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.846;
    color: #666666;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.oldie .submit-loader .s-loader {
    display: none;
}

.oldie .submit-loader .text-loader {
    display: block;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------------- 
 * ## loader animation 
 * --------------------------------------------------------------- */
.s-loader {
    margin: 1.2rem auto 3rem;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0.45rem);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0.45rem);
    transform: translateX(0.45rem);
}

.s-loader > div {
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: .9rem;
    -webkit-animation: bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

.s-loader .bounce1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
    animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.s-loader .bounce2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
    animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
```

```html
<?php
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'testemail@outlook.com';


if($_POST) {

    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
    $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phoneNumber']);
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
    $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

    // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }

    // Check Phone
    if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $phone)) {
        $error['phone'] = "Please enter a valid phone number.";
      }

    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
    // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }

    // Set Message
    $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
    $message .= "Contact Phone: " . $phone . "<br />";
    $message .= "Message: <br />";
    $message .= $contact_message;
    $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

    // Set From: header
    $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

    // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


    if (!$error) {

        ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
        $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
        else { echo "Something went wrong... Please try again."; }
        
    } # end if - no validation error

    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['phone'])) ? $error['phone'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;
        
        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<div class="default-form contact-form">
       <form method="post" action="" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
        <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="" placeholder="Complete Name" minlength="4" required="" aria-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" value="" placeholder="Your Email" required="" aria-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                                                       
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input placeholder="Phone" type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required="" aria-required="true">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            $('#phoneNumber').inputmask("(999) 999-9999");
                                        </script>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="contactSubject" id="contactSubject" value="" placeholder="Subject" required="" aria-required="true">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" value="" placeholder="Your Message" required="" aria-required="true">
                                    </div>                                   
                                   
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button class="full-width btn btn--primary">Submit</button>
                                        <div class="submit-loader">
                                            <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>
                                            <div class="s-loader">
                                                <div class="bounce1"></div>
                                                <div class="bounce2"></div>
                                                <div class="bounce3"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                            
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                            <!-- contact-warning -->
                            <div class="message-warning">
                                Something went wrong. Please try again.
                            </div> 
                        
                            <!-- contact-success -->
                            <div class="message-success">
                                Your message was sent, thank you!<br>
                            </div>
      </div>
      <!--End Default Form-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `preg_match()` to validate 10-digit mobile numbers:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $mobile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, ok so the preg-match validation is the culprit? The phone format that I'm trying to validate is (999) 999-9999

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.. I changed the inputmask to this format ("999-999-9999"), then also made a change to Php to match the js inputmask, it goes something like:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/', $phone)) {
```

$error['phone'] = "Please enter a valid phone number.";
}

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method :**

```
function validating($phone){
    $valid_number = filter_var($phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $valid_number = str_replace("-", "", $valid_number);
    if (strlen($valid_number) < 10 || strlen($valid_number) > 14) {
    echo "Invalid Number <br>";
    } else {
    echo "Valid Number <br>";
    }
}
$phone = "(999) 999-9999";
validating($phone);
```